# How can I get back a former value of input when unclicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Well, I'm planning my input elements' value to be hidden when clicked, but be shown again when clicked anywhere else.

Here's my HTML file:

```
<div id="iletisim">
<h2>İletişim</h2>
    <div id="bilgiler">
        <p>info@gmail.com</p>
        <p>211-22-67-09</p>
        <p>New Oakland - CA</p>
    </div>
    <div id = "formlar2">
        <form id="formlar">
            E-POSTA :   <input type="text" name="email" value="eposta adresinizi giriniz">
            TELEFON :   <input type="text" name="telefon" value="telefon numaranızı giriniz">
        </form>
        <textarea rows="10" cols="64">İstek ve şikayetlerinizi buraya yazabilirsiniz!</textarea>
        <input type="submit"></input>
    </div>
    <div id='linkler'>
        <a href='http://www.facebook.com'><img src='images/fb.png'></img></a>
        <a href='http://www.twitter.com'><img src='images/twt.png'></img></a>
        <a href='http://www.instagram.com'><img src='images/in.png'></img></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's jquery code I figured out:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#formlar2 input , textarea').click(function(){
        $(this).val('');
    });

    $('#iletisim p, #iletisim a, #iletisim h2').click(function(){
      var x = "eposta adresinizi giriniz"
      var y = "telefon numaranızı giriniz"
      var z = "İstek ve şikayetlerinizi buraya yazabilirsiniz!"
      $('#formlar2 input:nth-child(1)').val(x);
      $('#formlar2 input:nth-child(2)').val(y);
      $('textarea').val(z);
   });
});
```

I totally know if I tried to work this out this way, the original value will be shown ONLY when the mentioned elements in the jquery code are clicked.

So what is the solution for this, otherwise I have to mention every other element than my input elements. Any ideas will be very helpful, especially a shortcut way for this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: "... click elsewhere..." sounds like you want the onBlur event

Comment: As i happened to know a bit later, yes that was the one i wanted to know but unfortunately were unaware of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I did get you right you can use `blur` event:

```
$('input, textarea').on('blur', function(){
   //do your stuff here
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pueg3x8o/)

Answer (score 1):

The feature you are looking for is called placeholders.  Check out:

- [HTML5 Placeholder Input Fields Fixed with jQuery](http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html)
- [More information about events](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html)

Example from the link:

```
$("'[placeholder]'").focus(function() {
  var input = $(this);
  if (input.val() == input.attr("'placeholder'")) {
    input.val("''");
    input.removeClass("'placeholder'");
  }
}).blur(function() {
  var input = $(this);
  if (input.val() == "''" || input.val() == input.attr("'placeholder'")) {
    input.addClass("'placeholder'");
    input.val(input.attr("'placeholder'"));
  }
}).blur();
```

Comment: This is also a good point i think for other purposes, but the think i meant was the appearing and disappearing my input's value again and again when clicked different points. Thanks though, pal.